# how to scroll 2 divs at the same time with iScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll4

I have 2 divs that both uses iScroll. Now I would like both divs to scroll when one of them are scrolled.

I want them to scroll simultaneously

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollTo` method to scroll the second div at a specified position on scrolling any div. It takes three arugments out of which timeout is optional.

`scrollTo(x, y, timeout)` - scrolls to any x,y location inside the scrolling area.

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring the `div` as follows :

```
<div id=wrapper>
 <div id="scroller">
   <div id="div1">
     <div id="child1"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="div2">
     <div id="child2"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then define iscroll for `#wrapper` and you get to scroll both the div simultaneously. This is the easy way.

Or you can try to get the `onScroll event`. Though it is not possible to exactly get on scroll position during scroll but you can still get is in on `onScrollMove` and `onScrollEnd`. Hope this helps you.